# Can java import text methods

Tags: java, text, methods, import

To make my question abit more specific I'm wondering if a compiled java program can import methods from a simple "text.txt" file, basiclly from text characters?? Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Simple answer IMHO is no. Did I understand you well that you want to read the method from file and execute it? But there could be a workaround for this - fire compiler execution from program and if everything is ok, you can use this new class for example. But it depends on what you would like to do...

Comment: @Betlista yes it is possible, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, here is an example of how to do it: [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CompileString.htm). On that page a string is compiled but it is the same basic principle. If you read the stuff in your text file into a string you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It can, but if you want those methods to be written in standard Java then it will require a bit of technical creativity.

Essentially, you can use the "Scripting API" ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html ). This API allows you to execute "scripts" in any language as part of your greater Java application. To get it to run Java, you'd need to create a ScriptEngine implementation which could take the source, run it through the compiler API ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html ), and execute it.

If the method doesn't have to be coded in Java, then you can use the scripting API pretty much out-of-the-box, along with one of the standard scripting engines. (The JavaScript engine is very well tested, for example).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using BeanShell.

http://www.beanshell.org/

Been around for years, rock solid, works.

Answer (score 0):

1. All methods must be part of a class.
2. You can only use methods in bytecode.

IFF your text file defines an unique class, you can use the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and reflection to use such a method.